# How to add an administrator with bcrypt password encryption in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, encryption, web, bcrypt

I've encountered a "strange" issue while developing a website using symfony 2.6.
I've already setup all the security stuff, including password encryption on registration (with bcrypt) to User and Admin entities. Now I want to add an admin and a user to try if my login engine works well, but obviously I cannot register a new user/admin with my website because of the security engine (i.e. i cannot access to the addUser page, because there's not an admin registered). I tried to create an admin directly from phpMyAdmin console but, at the moment when I put the admin's password, it is saved as plaintext (differently from the registration phase in my engine, that stores encrypted passwords), so the login fails.

So, how can i solve this issue?

Hope all of you understood this, otherwise feel free to ask!

Thanks in advance,
Panc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I have found this great and simple [tutorial](http://donna-oberes.blogspot.it/2013/09/user-login-and-logout-step-by-step-with.html) that explains weel how to "autogenerate" a user using Doctrine's Fixtures, in which there's a method called "load" that simply does the following:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
  $user = new User();
  $user->setUsername("someuser");
  $user->setSalt(md5(uniqid()));
  $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
  $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword('blue', $user->getSalt()));
  $user->setEmail("someuser@mail.ca");

  $manager->persist($user);

  $manager->flush();
}
```

Also Thanks to @acontell to his response. Maybe my solution will help you in future. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use any webpage that generates bcrypt passwords such as this [one](https://www.dailycred.com/blog/12/bcrypt-calculator). Generate the password and store it encrypted in your database. Login using the user you created and the pass (obviously, the non-encrypted version of it).

It should work.

Comment: Thanks thanks!!! i'll try later and i'll tell you if I can login successfully! :)

Answer (score 2):

Symfony 3 ships a very useful command for this: `security:encode-password`

> The security:encode-password command encodes passwords according to
>   your   security configuration. This command is mainly used to generate
>   passwords for   the in_memory user provider type and for changing
>   passwords   in the database while developing the application.

`php ./bin/console security:encode-password --no-interaction _password_ "App\Entity\User"`

Give

```
 ------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Key                Value
 ------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Encoder used       Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder
  Encoded password   94H61KiSMDm60HL63z+s8AxLUTqwVv8aoKshC3X1q5A=
  Generated salt     tyPR/b4ussonYznhJ/bgtlTKSerBznRcNEPgSNmW
 ------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```